# Accessing HttpContext when processing DependencyTelemetry from HttpClient

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to access the HttpContext when logging dependencies so that I can track the user that made the request. However it always seems to lose the context. Is there any way I can get access to it?

```
public class MyProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor 
{
    public void Process(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var dependency = telemetry as DependencyTelemetry;

        if (dependency != null) {
            // This is always null when it's an HttpClient request.
            var context = HttpContext.Current; 
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've found the below workaround, although would be great if there is a better way of accessing HttpContext.

```
public class ApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetryFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple => false;

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(
        HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.GetRequestTelemetry();

        if (request != null) {
            request.Context.User.Id = HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name;
        }

        return continuation();
    }
}
```

I can then access Context.User.Id when processing a dependency telemetry.

**EDIT**

I tell a lie, that only works for Web Service calls. The properties of UserContext are all null when it's an Http call.